# VerticalGridFragment in leanback library binds data incorrectly for the last row

Tags: android-tv, leanback

[image]I am using VerticalGridFragment to populate my single list of content. I am using ArrayObjectAdapter for the adapter. What I have noticed is that last row data is incorrectly arranged. For e.g:

1) Please see image attachment above.

2) If my list is made of 5 columns and I have only 4 content to display in the last row then leanback will display content in 2nd,3rd,4th and 5th slots and first slot will be empty.

3) In other case, last 5 content were displayed in 1,2,3,4 slots and instead of filling the last content in 5th slot, last content was placed in the center (3rd slot) of a *complete new row*.

There are many more inconsistent data binding when it comes to last row.

Have any of you noticed this kind of behavior in leanback library? Or any solution to fix this?

Here is the extract of my code:

```
private volatile ArrayObjectAdapter listAdapter;

private void setupUX() {
   setSearchAffordanceColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.search_bg_color));
    VerticalGridPresenter verticalGridPresenter = new VerticalGridPresenter();
    verticalGridPresenter.setNumberOfColumns(NUM_COL);
    setGridPresenter(verticalGridPresenter);
    CardView cardView = new CardView();
    queriesFired = new HashMap<>();
    dataHandler = new Handler(getActivity().getMainLooper());
    listAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardView);
    setAdapter(listAdapter);
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> startEntranceTransition(), 500);
}

private void populateData() {
    ....
    listAdapter.add(uiContent);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using for this?

Comment: Please find the code posted along with the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem - I was setting setMaxLines(2) for the image cards that are used to populate the list (so that I can display movie titles in two lines). This seems to mess up the layout of the verticalGridFragment.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. It also works for me and this saved me from taking a few more cups of coffee))

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem happens. if you test on kitkat device. test on marshmallow or above devces. this problem will not happen.